# Open CV detecting faces in java

Tags: java, opencv

I tried to do this samle:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html
But every time I got "Detected 0 faces".
I have Windows 7 x64, all libraries (opencv_java245.dll) are connected. I tried version 2.4.4 and 2.4.5, and I tried different image formats(png, jpg, bmp) and different image, but the result is always the same "Detected 0 faces".
Why this might not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by transferring the xml file from my project to another location on the computer

Comment: Moving the .xml and .png file to different location is not solved my issue. it still shows the error message "Detected 0 faces". Do you have some other alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and I change the code

```
//CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(getClass().getResource("/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath());
//Mat image = Highgui.imread(getClass().getResource("/lena.png").getPath());
```

to

```
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("E:/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"); // With absolute location.
Mat image = Highgui.imread("E:/lena.png"); // With absolute location.
```

then it works.

There is something wrong with the file location in the origin code.

```
String lbpcascadesFilePath = getClass().getResource("/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml").getPath();
// The fiel path you got is like /E:/Programmer/EclipseWorkspace/JavaProject/TestOpenCV/bin/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml
System.out.println(lbpcascadesFilePath); 
// trim first '/', or the file cannot be read in Windows.
lbpcascadesFilePath = lbpcascadesFilePath.substring(1);
// Then it is OK to load the file.
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(lbpcascadesFilePath);
```

Then do the same to the image file.

```
String imgFilePath = getClass().getResource("/lena.png").getPath();
System.out.println(imgFilePath); // like /E:/Programmer/EclipseWorkspace/JavaProject/TestOpenCV/bin/lena.png
imgFilePath = imgFilePath.substring(1);  // trim first "/", or the file cannot be read in Windows.
Mat image = Highgui.imread(imgFilePath);
```